# Cannot see contents of directory with local Apache

Tags: windows, apache2

I have set up apache2 on my Win7 box and would like to be able to see the contents of a directory.

For example, I would like to navigate to:

```
http://localhost/tutorial/
```

and see a list the different html, js, and css files I have created.  I've already redirected Apache to check the C:\ApacheHtDoc\ folder as the source directory.  I've tried looking at folder permissions, but I'm not sure how to see the contents of the C:\ApacheHtDoc\ directory and the subfolders I'm bound to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the directive in `Apache2.2\conf\httpd.conf`

```
<Directory "C:\ApacheHtDoc\">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

If you haven't, add that and restart apache.

**Edit**

Path for the `httpd.conf` may vary according to your install.